# Rotation implementation errors

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am trying to implement a rotation for a camera with the following function

```
mat3 rotate(const float degrees, const vec3& axis) {

    mat3 matrix=mat3(cos(degrees),0.0f,-sin(degrees),
        0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,
        sin(degrees),0.0f,cos(degrees)
        );
    mat4 m4=mat4(matrix)  ;
    return (m4 * vec4(axis,1));
}
```

However I am not able to convert mat4 to mat3. Also the multiplication of mat4 and vec3 is giving compilation errors

Comment: Where did mat3, mat4, and vec3 come from? Is it glm?

Comment: Also what are the error messages you're getting?

Comment: @DavidSaxon yes i m using glm . I get errors like " cannot convert parameter 1 from 'glm::detail::tvec4<T>' to 'const glm::detail::tmat3x3<T> &'

Comment: `matrix * vector = vector` - rotating a vector gets you a new vector pointing in a different direction. If I'm not mistaken you're rotating `axis` around the y axis. If this is what you want to do, just change the return type and `return matrix * axis;`. If you want to create a matrix for rotation *around* `axis`, see e.g. [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

Answer (score 3):

In the return statement you're multiplying a 4x4 matrix by a 4 dimensional vector.

```
return (m4 * vec4(axis,1));
```

This returns a vec4, yet your function states it returns a mat3.

But I really think you need to review what you're trying to do. A camera uses a 4x4 matrix to define it's view matrix and glm already supplies convenience functions for rotating matrices.

```
glm::mat4 viewMatrix( 1.0f );
viewMatrix *= glm::rotate( angle, axis );
```

Comment: I agree , but since I am new to opengl I want to actually implement the rotation logic without using the glm API's . Also I tried 
return (matrix * axis);  but I still get error cannot convert from 'glm::detail::tvec3<T>' to 'const glm::detail::tmat3x3<T>'

Answer (score 1):

There are rules for matrix multiplication, specifically: **For AB the number of columns in matrix A must be equal to the number of rows in matrix B**. Multiplying a matrix by a vector is valid because vector is like a one dimensional matrix, however, it must follow the above rule so multiplying a `mat4` (a 4 by 4 matrix) by `vec3` (a 3x1 matrix) is impossible because the number of columns is not equal to the number of rows, what you can do is create a `vec4` (4x1 matrix) and fill the last component with 1, thus allowing you to multiply it with a `mat4` matrix. You can read more about matrix multiplications [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Matrix_product_.28two_matrices.29).

Another thing, like @David Saxon said, you have function returning `mat3` while your return statement looks like this `return (m4 * vec4(axis,1));`, which will result in a `vec4` (4x1 matrix), which is probably the reason you're getting this compilation error.

If you only want rotate a vector you don't have to use a 4x4 matrix, you can just multiply the `mat3` by the `vec3` you want to rotate, which will result in a `vec3` representing the rotated vector.